# Google Fusion Table Query: Color Change By Population Density

Tags: google-fusion-tables

How do I change the colors of the map I created in fusion tables to represent population density?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach for U.S. state data, current as of April 2014:

http://epiphron.tumblr.com/post/82205653723/how-to-make-colored-state-maps-with-google-tools

In short, get data into Google Fusion Tables, merge it with a publicly available file that has shape info for each state (or country, if that's your thing), and map it directly in Fusion Tables.

The colors can be customized under the Feature Map menu in the Fusion Tables map. You can either do a gradient map, or segment the colors by various groupings. The latter is probably more useful for density data, as with the standard gradient settings, most entities will appear to be the same color, because the distribution of population density tends to be skewed, with a few entities (e.g. DC) with very high values.